# Path finding program using Recursive function in c

Tags: c, recursion, path-finding

I need to write a C program to find the shortest path from **0x0** to **mxn** *( for more simplicity, here, I will call these points S for Start and E for End)* point in 2d array using **recursive function**. But I don't know any algorithms, I just know very little and basic things about C, and I don't know how and where to start. 
I did some researches and wrote something like this, but it has two major problems, **1) it doesn't backtrack**, **2) it doesn't automatically move itself.** I want to use recursion for auto move but I couldn't do it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#define N 6
/// For printing the final solution Matrix
void printSolution(int solution[N][N]){
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
            printf(" %d ", solution[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
    }
}
/// For checking if solution coordinate is in matrix or not
bool isSafe(int maze[N][N], int x, int y){
    if (x >= 0 && x < N && y >= 0 && y < N && maze[x][y] == 1)
        return true;
    return false;
}
/// For looking to the neighbour cells
bool lookRight(int maze[N][N], int x, int y){
    if(maze[x][y+1]==0)
        return false;
    if(maze[x][y+1]==1)
        return true;
}
bool lookDown(int maze[N][N], int x, int y){
    if(maze[x+1][y]==0)
        return false;
    if(maze[x+1][y]==1)
        return true;
}
bool lookLeft(int maze[N][N], int x, int y){
    if(maze[x][y-1]==0)
        return false;
    if(maze[x][y-1]==1)
        return true;
}
bool lookUp(int maze[N][N], int x, int y){
    if(maze[x-1][y]==0)
        return false;
    if(maze[x-1][y]==1)
        return true;
}
/// For moving in available direction
bool moveRight(int maze[N][N], int x,int y){
    if (lookRight(maze, x, y)==true && isSafe(maze, x, y)==true)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
bool moveDown(int maze[N][N], int x,int y){
    if (lookDown(maze, x, y)==true && isSafe(maze, x, y)==true)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
bool moveLeft(int maze[N][N], int x,int y){
    if (lookLeft(maze, x, y)==true && isSafe(maze, x, y)==true)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
bool moveUp(int maze[N][N], int x,int y){
    if (lookUp(maze, x, y)==true && isSafe(maze, x, y)==true)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
/// For solving the main maze
bool solveMaze(int maze[N][N], int x, int y, int xFinal, int yFinal){
    int solution[N][N]={{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                        {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                        {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                        {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                        {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                        {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}};
    if (moveRight(maze, x, y)==true){
        solution[x][y+1]=1;
    }
    if (moveDown(maze, x, y)==true){
        solution[x+1][y]=1;
    }
    if (moveLeft(maze, x, y)==true){
        solution[x][y-1]=1;
    }
    if (moveUp(maze, x, y)==true){
        solution[x-1][y]=1;
    }
    printSolution(solution);
}
/// Main maze
int main() {         //S
    int maze[N][N] = {{1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1},
                      {1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1},
                      {1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1},
                      {1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1},
                      {1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1},
                      {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1}};
    solveMaze(maze, 0, 0, N, N);    //E
    return 0;}
```

My main goal in this program is to find shortest available path to go from, **Start** to **End**. I need to use recursive function to be able to move and search paths. But in this code I only can manually enter each point to check all other parts. For example:

```
 int main() {
    int maze[N][N] = { {1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1},
                       {1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1},
                       {1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1},
                       {1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1},
                       {1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1},
                       {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1} };
    solveMaze(maze, 2, 2, N, N);
    return 0;
}
```

in here, my input is element (2, 2) *( Why did I give it (2,2) instead of (0,0) because I wanted to show better, in the finished program it will start from **0x0** point or **S** for short)*.

```
{ {1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1},
  {1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1},
  {1, 0, (1), 0, 0, 1}, // by element(2, 2) I mean this (1) in here
  {1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1},
  {1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1},
  {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1} }
```

First it will check its right, it is 0, so it won't do anything. Next it will check down, it is 1, so it will change 0 to 1 in the solution matrix. I think it is clear now, so the output for this input will look like this:

```
 0  0  0  0  0  0
 0  0  1  0  0  0
 0  0  0  0  0  0
 0  0  1  0  0  0
 0  0  0  0  0  0
 0  0  0  0  0  0
```

This was manual input, but I want it to be able to move automatically, in here 1 is path and 0 is wall.

```
int main() {
    int maze[N][N] = { {S, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1},
                       {1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1},
                       {1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1},
                       {1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1},
                       {1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1},
                       {1, 1, 1, 0, 0, E} };
    solveMaze(maze, 2, 2, N, N);
    return 0;
}
```

It should start from S and should stop in E, and I have to write a function to do this until it reaches the E.

The second problem is it don't backtrack, for example:

```
int main() {
    int maze[N][N] = { {S, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1},
                       {1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1},
                       {1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1},
                       {1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1},
                       {1, 1, 1, X, 0, 1},
                       {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, E} };
    solveMaze(maze, 2, 2, N, N);
    return 0;
  }
```

in here my program will go to X *( X in here is just 1 in the matrix, I wrote X to show you what I exactly mean )* first ( *if we consider the first problem is solved and it can move automatically* ), then it will check its four neighbors, and they all are 0. What I want is, it goes back to 1, then resume from there. If everything is right it should move up, and the output should look like this:

```
 S  0  1  1  1  1
 1  0  1  0  0  1
 1  0  1  0  0  1
 1  0  1  0  0  1
 1  1  1  0  0  1
 0  0  0  0  0  E
```

and not like this:

```
 S  0  0  0  0  0
 1  0  0  0  0  0
 1  0  0  0  0  0
 1  0  0  0  0  0
 1  1  1  1  0  0
 0  0  0  0  0  E
```

[This is the original Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xzz6X.png)

Comment: Step one: Find a HelloWorld and make it run and output.

Comment: Step two: Read. A lot. Start here [tour], [ask], https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/ , https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/ , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm

Comment: Step three: Write a program that is actually aware of the maze. I.e. has datastructures containing the wall/path information and is able to output the maze, for debugging purposes.

Comment: Step four: Starting with extremely small mazes, e.g. 2x2 and 3x3, write simple brute force approach.

Comment: thank you for your help, this is my homework. I don't have any algorithm courses in my lessons. They teach us only basic C things and we just finished the pointers, in 2 weeks, and this is the homework as you can see. thank you man. Is there any way to solve this without any algorithms?

Comment: Sure. Do step three and show it here. Then we can discuss step four.

Comment: @Yunnosch Hi how are you?, I did some researches and came up with something like this, and I updated my question can you please check it out and help me? Thank you

Comment: Good work. Now please explain in detail, with examples and possibly observed output what you mean with "1) it doesn't backtrack, 2) it doesn't automatically move itself".

Comment: I have two matrices, first one for the input and second one for the output. My goal is to check the first matrix for available path, if there is one, write 1 in the second matrix. My program will kind of check every possible way, but there is a problem, if there is no way to move, it won't go back.It will stuck there. The other problem is, I have to use recursive function to go and search the maze

Comment: For example: in here program will check element (3, 3) if there is a any way to go it will print 1 in the second solution. `int main() {
    int maze[N][N] = {{S, 0, 1, 1, 1},
                      {1, 0, 1, 0, 1},
                      {1, 0, 1, 0, 1},
                      {1, 0, 1, 0, 1},
                      {1, 1, 1, 0, G}};
    solveMaze(maze, 3, 3, N, N);
    return 0;
}`

Comment: Please do the explaining inside the question, that offers much more space and better formatting features, apart from not hiding useful info...

Comment: @Yunnosch I'm so sorry about my SO I'm new here, I did my best to explain everything to you, and I hope I don't waste your time

Comment: Be patient, you are doing well. Somebody already considers your question good enough now. I will have a look.

Comment: I do not get this "input is element (2, 2)..." and what follows. You are supposed to start at "S" or "0,0" aren't you? So why start in the middle? Let's not bother about backtracking at first. I propose that you first try small mazes (6x6 is a little bigger than I would have done, but it is fine, you seem to be doing well) which also have a single good path to "E". Just make some explicit examples. You seem to have already had that idea. Good. I do not understand however, why your program goes to "X". I understand that is is 0, i.e. not path. Can you explain or find out?

Comment: By the way, I think your question also good enough to reopen now. But first I try to help you make it even better, because once I vote and some other users close it again, I will not be able reopen-vote again.

Comment: @Yunnosch First of all thank you for your help and your patient, I improved my question a little bit to become more easier to understand and I also attached the original question.

Comment: Ok, I have created a modified version of your code which can at least find the end in case of trivial mazes (i.e. there is only ever one possible path ahead). First I will help you to get that done, too. As long as there are no other answers this is allowed (as soon as anybody posts an answer you are not supposed to relevantly change the question anymore). On that foundation, you will be able to ask a focused question on backtracking (which becomes necessary when there are dead ends, but not before). If you agree to edit your shown code towards this goal I will lead you.

Comment: Assuming you follow my hints here are the first things to do: 1) Change to check "safe" on the place you consider going to, not the one your are on, which will always be sage 2) Be aware of directions, i.e. anytime you decided to go into a direction, write it into a variable (values 0 init, 1, 2, 3, 4). 3) introduce an additional check to prevent ever going back into the direction you came from 4) when you decided on a direction to go, then not only mark that place as 1, also update the current coordinates x,y 5) do all of that in a loop within `solveMaze()`, ending when x,y == N-1, N-1.

Comment: 6) each step print a debug "Now at x,y" 7) print a debug "Stuck!" whenever none of the four directions can be stepped, because of wall, because of out of maze or because of not going back, break the loop in this case

Comment: I did those things and got a nice solution printout from your printSolution(), which looks exactly like the trivial maze. Feel free to ask if you have trouble, but please spend some time trying.